# redirect action link to canvas app without error alert

Tags: facebook-graph-api, actionlink

I am integrating [action links](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/action-links/) into my application and when re-directing  user outside of Facebook, am getting the Sorry, Something Went Wrong error, per the spec. The spec indicates that this is the symptom of redirecting users outside of Facebook. Thus, I would gladly have this as an app on my page if it meant that users would not see that error.

Is it possible to bypass the alert if I am redirecting to page on Facebook?

Comment: How about _testing_ it for yourself …?

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think of that. Seriously, yeah, we tried but were still getting the same error.

Comment: It seems that this must not be possible. When we try to redirect to the apps.facebook.com domain, it says its an invalid redirect domain. Has anyone come across a solution that works?